# Cannot use com.sun.net.httpserver - Java 8

Tags: java, import, java-8, package

I am trying to create a simple server program to handle http requests. So with minimum search, I stumbled upon the oracle documentation for the `httpserver` class, inside the `com.sun.net` package. I'm relatively new to Java, so I thought that a class "sponsored" by Oracle itself would be included in the default libraries.

Unfortunately, that was not the case. After a lot of trials for possible syntax-import errors (various kinds of error arouse) and having installed the Oracle JDK 8 correctly on my Ubuntu machine, the compiler said that the package did not exist. What do I have to do to get the package to work?

Comment: Don't treat `com.sun.xxx` packages as if they're part of the standard library. Oracles java distribution may the most common, but it isn't the only one.

Comment: What is the solution, in that case? I'm not biased on the answer, that's why I am asking.

Comment: Did it really say that the package did not exist? What was the actual error message? Literally, not a paraphrase. Precision is important.

Comment: It did really say it did not exist, but it was something very simple after all. See my answer. At least I was genuinely tricked by the package name, thinking it was actually the class I wanted. Of course that was largely because I am new to Java, but it would be nice to help other newbies who get stuck on the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did finally make it work. Mostly, it was a misunderstanding from my place, since I only imported up to a point that was wrong - that is,I only imported `com.sun.net.httpserver`, thinking the latter part was the actual class I wanted, but it was merely the package name. So then I proceeded to import `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`, then the rest of my classes. Finally a `com.sun.net.httpserver.*` would work perfectly fine. It seems stupid now that I figured it out, but I think I will leave it here just in case anyone has the same misunderstanding - I already see 1 favourite on the question. And of course, as others have pointed out, the package is not part of the standard java libraries, but I used Oracle Java specifically for that.

P.S. The class is really useful, unlike what the other answer implies, but  now I have stumbled upon another problem regarding reading the request body right, something that might have to do with the locale of the client-server, and I will now procced to search that.. Just a warning for anyone thinking of using the package.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly try to avoid com.sun.xxx package, as those are internalls of Oracle/Sun java implementation.

Secondly, why not use libraries from apache ?  See https://hc.apache.org/

EDITED:

You can also look on http://sparkjava.com/ , not tested but examples looks promising and they are using Java 8 nice features.

Comment: The `sun.*` classes are internals of the implementation, and there is a specific warning in the Javadoc saying so and cautioning against their use in application code. `com.sun.*` classes are supported, as in this case, and as in the case of JNDI providers for example.

Comment: Even the com.sun classes are proprietary classes of Oracle, and not contained in other Non-Oracle JDK/JRE. This should be reason enough to avoid using those classes.

Comment: @ChristophBimminger Eclipse Temurin is a non-Oracle JDK to my knowledge and still it contains com.sun classes like in particular `com.sun.net.httpserver.*` . At least up to version JDK17.